# How lexicons work in MarkLogic?

Tags: indexing, marklogic, lexicon

How `lexicons` are different from `indexes` in **Marklogic**.

Please explain with example.

Answer (score 5):

It's all here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon

If after reading the docs, update your question with something more specific and you'll get a more specific answer..